# mock variable constant environment

Tags: unit-testing, variables, jestjs, environment-variables, nestjs

how to mock a constant variable in NestJs with JEST?

I need in my tests to change the value of one of the constants

**constants.js**

```
export const VAR_DATA_NAME_1 = process.env.DATA_NAME_1 
export const VAR_DATA_NAME_2 = process.env.DATA_NAME_2  
export const VAR_FLG_ACTIVE = 1
```

**service.ts**

```
private async getPrices(name string)
{
  if(name === VAR_DATA_NAME_2)
  {
      return ........
  }
}
```

Comment: isn't it simpler to check cases with different `name` argument?

Comment: It is an example raised because I have different functions that use constants with environment

Comment: the way the question asked - it's not obvious why you need to have const mocked

Answer (score 0):

Again, it's simpler to pass different `name` and check, but you can try:

```
// your-awesome.test.ts
import * as envConsts from '../config';

envConsts.VAR_DATA_NAME_1 = 'mock_value';

it('VAR_DATA_NAME_1 will be equal to "mock_value"', () => {
   // do test in assumption 
   // VAR_DATA_NAME_1 === 'mock_value'
})
```